# symfony2 store read-only configuration

Tags: json, symfony, readonly

What is the best way to store read-only configuration in symfony?

I have some name/description pairs inside a JSON file, currently sitting in a bundle's resource directory that I'd like to use inside my controllers and views but don't want to insert into my database.

And what do you recommend for parsing / getting the values to display? Making a specific service for the DiC doesn't feel to good tbh..

Comment: What is wrong with `parameters.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

Same scenario with me ,I worked with ymls file , create a yml file in config folder like product.yml , parse it in controller then send its josn to template .
And this is the right way to play with static data .